# Preciso recuperar as informações de uma página. Como posso continuar o que comecei?

Tags: php, regex

```
<?php 

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.cidades.ibge.gov.br/xtras/uf.php?lang=&coduf=17&search=tocantins');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$conteudo = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);

highlight_string($conteudo);

?>
```

Todo o conteúdo da página que eu estou recuperando está dentro de **$conteudo**. Dentro dessa `<ul>` terá dezenas ou centenas de resultados e eu preciso pegar todos.

```
<ul id="lista_municipios">
    <li id="">
        <a href="perfil.php?lang=&codmun=170025&search=tocantins|item1">item2</a>
    </li>
    <li>....
    <li>....
</ul>
```

Preciso pegar `item1` e `item2`.

Comment: Se entendi bem, você pode usar phpQuery, ele simula o jquery só que em php...

Comment: Acha que posso chegar mais fácil ao objetivo usando phpQuery?

Comment: É uma das alternativas, acho que é bem de opinião pessoal essa escolha, vou colocar um exemplo que utilizei em consulta de CEP para você analisar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui está um exemplo utilizando phpQuery-one-file para consulta de CEP; A parte do cURL não está inclusa pois o foco é o uso do phpQuery; Essa é uma das várias soluções possíveis.

> phpQuery: https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

```
$body = $client->send($request)->getBody(); //Aqui seria seu HTML
    //Inclusão do phpQuery
    if (!method_exists('phpQuery', 'newDocumentHTML'))
        require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'phpQuery-onefile.php';
    //Inicialização do documento, substitua $body pela sua variável contendo o HTML;
    $doc = \phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($body, $charset = 'utf-8');
    $resultados = [];
        //Itera sobre as linhas da tabela;
        foreach(\phpQuery::pq('table[cellpadding="5"]')->find('tr') as $linha) {
            $dados = [];
            foreach(\phpQuery::pq($linha)->find('td') as $coluna) {
                $valor = htmlspecialchars_decode(trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', \phpQuery::pq($coluna)->html())));
                $dados[] = $valor;
            }
            $dadosFinal['logradouro'] = $dados[0];
            $dadosFinal['bairro'] = $dados[1];
            $dadosFinal['localidade'] = $dados[2];
            $dadosFinal['uf'] = $dados[3];
            $dadosFinal['cep'] = $dados[4];
            $resultados[] = $dadosFinal;
        }
return $resultados;
```

Aplicando a sua necessidade, faria algo como:

```
//Inclusão do phpQuery
if (!method_exists('phpQuery', 'newDocumentHTML'))
    require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'phpQuery-onefile.php';
//Inicialização do documento, substitua $body pela sua variável contendo o HTML;
$doc = \phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($body, $charset = 'utf-8');

foreach(\phpQuery::pq('ul#lista_municipios')->find('li') as $linha) {
    $valor = htmlspecialchars_decode(\phpQuery::pq($linha)->html());//item2
    $valorAttr = htmlspecialchars_decode(\phpQuery::pq($linha)->attr('href')); //Item1 (valor do href)
    $item1 = explode('|', $valorAttr)[1]; //mantive $valorAttr caso você precise. 
}
```

Em fim precisaria de testes e adaptações para sua necessidade;

Comment: Que legal ... não entendi nada. Mas tipo: aonde ele começa lendo a varíavel `$conteudo` que está todos os dados da página?

Comment: A variável $body, recebe todo o conteúdo html da página, onde está a linha newDocumentHTML, ele inicializa seu objeto com o html passado pelo $body; Alterei a resposta agora comentando um pouco melhor a linha onde inicializa tudo.. Desculpe caso não tenha sido muito claro...

Comment: Conforme mostra aqui http://pastebin.com/vwJyg2bi, eu consegui fazer a contagem de quantos registros tem dentro dessa **ul**. Mandei ele procurar dentro de **li** os hiperlinks(<a>) que é aonde está todo o conteúdo que precisa ser recuperado, no caso `ìtem1` e `item2`. Pode me dar mais uma força pra recuperar `ìtem1` e `item2`?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Tente algo como: `$valor = htmlspecialchars_decode(\phpQuery::pq($linha)->html());` Assim você recupera o valor, `$valorAttr = htmlspecialchars_decode(\phpQuery::pq($linha)->attr('href'));` Recuperar o valor do href para depois aplicar o filtro e pegar seu valor do item1

Comment: Falta pouquíssimo: **perfil.php?lang=&codmun=170025&search=tocantins|abreulandia** ... pra pegar `abreulandia` vou precisar de um regex?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Você pode usar o explode(), e pegar a segunda posição do array.